# How to set a new passsord before writing nfc tag on phone in android programatically

Tags: android, nfc

Hi I'm doing one app which is nfc reading and writer app in this app i can able to read the data from the tag and associate the custom tag to the data.I'm stuck in this that is how to set desired password to written tag to protect from overwriting and at the same time how can i ask user to enter password for reading the same nfc tag.Please somebody help me to get me out of this.

```
 adapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
 pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
    IntentFilter tagDetected = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED);
    tagDetected.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    writeTagFilters = new IntentFilter[]{tagDetected};





  btnWrite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mytag = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
            //Toast.makeText(ctx,"taggggg"+mytag,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if (mytag == null) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.error_detected), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {


                    try {
                        Toast.makeText(ctx, ctx.getString(R.string.ok_writing), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        protect(mytag);
                    }catch (Exception e)
                    {


                }

         }
     });







         private void protect(Tag tag1) {
    MifareUltralight nfc=MifareUltralight.get(tag1);
    try {
        byte[] response = nfc.transceive(new byte[]{
                (byte) 0x1B, // PWD_AUTH
                pwd[0], pwd[1], pwd[2], pwd[3]
        });
        if ((response != null) && (response.length >= 2)) {
            byte[] pack = Arrays.copyOf(response, 2);
            // TODO: verify PACK to confirm that tag is authentic (not really,
            // but that whole PWD_AUTH/PACK authentication mechanism was not
            // really meant to bring much security, I hope; same with the
            // NTAG signature btw.)
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {

    }
    try {
        byte[] response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
                (byte) 0xA2, // WRITE
                (byte) 39,   // page address
                pwd[0], pwd[1], pwd[2], pwd[3]
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        byte[] response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
                (byte) 0xA2, // WRITE
                (byte) 40,   // page address
                pack[0], pack[1],   // bytes 0-1 are PACK value
                (byte) 0, (byte) 0  // other bytes are RFU and must be written as 0
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        byte[] response = new byte[0];
        response = nfc.transceive(new byte[] {
                (byte) 0x30, // READ
                (byte) 38    // page address
        });

            try {
                if ((response != null) && (response.length >= 16)) {  // read always returns 4 pages
                    boolean prot = false;  // false = PWD_AUTH for write only, true = PWD_AUTH for read and write
                    int authlim = 0; // value between 0 and 7
                    response = nfc.transceive(new byte[]{
                            (byte) 0xA2, // WRITE
                            (byte) 38,   // page address
                            (byte) ((response[0] & 0x078) | (prot ? 0x080 : 0x000) | (authlim & 0x007)),
                            response[1], response[2], response[3]  // keep old value for bytes 1-3, you could also simply set them to 0 as they are currently RFU and must always be written as 0 (response[1], response[2], response[3] will contain 0 too as they contain the read RFU value)
                    });
                }
            }catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        write(txt.getText().toString(), mytag);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

 How to achieve below output:

[new Password image to protect the nfc tag][1]


[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOEOD.png



In manifest file i included these permissions

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<action android:name="com.android.nfc_extras.action.MIFARE_ACCESS_DETECTED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.nfc"
    android:required="true"
    />



   <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

 Please help me
```

Comment: Passwords are handled by Account Manager along with auth token, username. You need to extend Accountauthenticatoractivity for the UI and implement AbstractAccountAuthenticator for the model. The manifest needs a few extra lines mostly referring to a resource xml file. Post back and I will help you out.

Comment: will you please explain in detail or any source code recommended by you?

Comment: what are the things to do?